# How to include PHP variable in Mysql statement

Tags: php, mysql

I'm sorry for this newbie question...
Could someone help me with the following:

How can I insert my $test variable into the Mysql statement?

Below my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM linkbuilding WHERE branche= '[here I want to insert $test]'"

$test = zakelijk
```

Comment: This question has already been asked here is the link :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement#:~:text=The%20rules%20of%20adding%20a,No%20exceptions.

Comment: Fairly sure the duplicate also talks about using prepared statements as well. But - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php.